# In Django how can I run the same function from views multiple times without refreshing the page?

Tags: python, django, web-applications, django-views

On one of my pages in my web app, I want to be able to view the disk space left on the server & I want that information to update every 30 seconds they are on the page. So far I was able to create a button that runs the function and displays the results, however, I have been unsuccessful in finding a way to call that function automatically. I have tried 'sched' with no luck and when I tried using a loop, it just slowed down my server. Any feedback or advice would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Use ajax or websockets.

Comment: Can ajax be used to run function automatically? I'm not worried about a page refresh, but rather the function running without having to click the button every time.